# Youtube/video playback in a android webview app

Tags: java, android, webview, youtube, android-webview

I recently made a website (www.fruitboompje.com).
Now I am trying to make a mobile android app for my website.
The mobile version of the site works great in chrome!
But with this test app I have now it will not load the video/music...
Can somebody help me with this?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.fruitboompje.music;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.fruitboompje.com/");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

    }
}
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.fruitboompje.music">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use the YouTube API for a native android library.

Comment: Thank you for helping! Adding the YouTube API worked fine for me!

Comment: no problem, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping Shark! Adding the YouTube API worked fine for me!

Comment: Feel free to post an answer on how you solved it and accept it, if you wish. It will help others that will face the same problem eventually.